# Air connections to server problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, air, connectivity

We have developed an Air application to deliver course material to clients. However, some clients are experiencing connectivity issues to our server, which we have managed to duplicate.

Some background. The App makes jQuery $.ajax POST requests to the server to log the user in using their username and password. The server responds with a json encoded response. This works perfectly except for particular scenarios, where the ajax attempt just times out trying to reach the server.

We managed to duplicate this issue by doing the following:

1. Boot computer.
2. Before internet connection has established itself, launch the Air app.
3. Attempt to log in.

You can re-load the app, log off Windows & back in, stand on your head... the app will continuously report a connection failure ("Unable to connect..." < our timeout message after 15 seconds). The only remedy is a full reboot of Windows and to wait for something like Skype to connect, thereby ensuring a server connection is possible.

We suspect the issue is related to some level of caching that Air does, or something that Air creates on boot, related to an internet connection.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a crossdomain.xml file in the root directory of the website you are connecting to for the data call? [tutorial](http://www.moock.org/asdg/technotes/crossDomainPolicyFiles/)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: No, but the website accepts the current connections just fine. Its more a case that it does not even get to the server. Something in Air gets locked. Could even be jquery, yet I doubt it.